# Receive then implement .js files from server in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that, when clicked, needs to display a modal to the user. For convenience we would like to pull all the necessary code for the modal from a server and then execute the JavaScript in the context of the extension, before displaying anything to the user.

(running a Node.js server)

Is there a way to do this?

If not, any suggestions on alternative routes we could take?

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have a read through https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

In short - it's possible, but you need to serve the script over HTTPS, or else Chrome will reject the origin. You also need to explicitly write the CSP in the manifest.

"Convenience" is a strange word to use here though. What if the network is flaky or slow?

Comment: So all scripts loaded from white-listed sites will run in the context of the extension?